# Get array of all matches in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

This is my current code:

```
$wonAwards = $altdb->get_var("SELECT achievement_id 
                                FROM user_1
                               WHERE isTold='false'");
```

Currently, `$wonAwards` is set equal to the first result of the sql query. Is it possible to set `$wonAwards` equal to an array of all the results of the query?

//////////////////  Full Function

```
function the_header_function(){ //called when wordpress header is loaded
    if (is_user_logged_in()){ //checks if user is logged in
        global $altdb;  //wp global database object
        $user_info = wp_get_current_user();
        $wonAwards = $altdb->query("SELECT achievement_id FROM user_".$user_info->ID." WHERE isTold='false'"); //query
        if(is_array($wonAwards)) $hello='true';
        if(!is_array($wonAwards)) $hello='false';
        if($wonAwards != ''){
            echo "<script>jQuery(document).ready( function(){alert('".$hello."');});</script>";
        }
    }
}
```

As for checking what the result of my query was, I simply changed this:

```
echo "<script>jQuery(document).ready( function(){alert('".$hello."');});</script>";
```

to this:

```
echo "<script>jQuery(document).ready( function(){alert('".$wonAwards."');});</script>";
```

Comment: We have no idea what `$altdb` is

Comment: $altdb is just an object containing the database info allowing me to make a connection and run a query. I just need to know how to get an array as a result from a SELECT query

Comment: @ShahmeerNavid: Usually the result of the query is an array, and your statement should be working, the issue I guess is with `get_var`, perhaps it's getting only the first element of the array. If you have its code please post it, also, how do you know `$wonAwards` only contains the first result, how did you test it?

Comment: @Mr.TAMER I have also tried the code with this: $wonAwards = $altdb->query("SELECT achievement_id FROM user_1 WHERE isTold='false'"); and it yields that same result (I am using wordpress's global database object to connect to database).

Comment: I will post my full function.

Comment: @Shahmeer Navid: "just an object containing the database info allowing me to make a connection and run a query" --- explains nothing. We haven't seen that class thus don't know how to work with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to the [Documentation Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), `get_var` will give you a single result, and `query` will give you the number of results.

What you really wants (getting all results) can be achieved by the `get_results` method, so you should write:

```
$wonAwards = $altdb->get_results("SELECT achievement_id 
                                FROM user_1
                               WHERE isTold='false'");
```

Try it and tell us if it works, hope that's helpful.

Comment: Welcome, the documentation is always the way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

As i understand that you want to set array instead of equals
Hope this will work:

```
$wonAwards = $altdb->get_var("SELECT achievement_id 
                            FROM user_1
                           WHERE isTold 
                           IN ('false', 'true', 'another_value', 'some_other')");
```

**Edit:** for @Shahmeer Navid
if you have some data in an array like

```
$array = array("data1", "data2", "data3");
$implode = implode("', '", $array);

//Output or $implode
data1', 'data2', 'data3

//apply on query
$wonAwards = $altdb->get_var("SELECT achievement_id 
                            FROM user_1
                           WHERE isTold 
                           IN ('$implode')");
```

**PS** Also use `mysql_real_escape_string()` if you get the data from the client

Comment: Could you explain the last line? specifically, the parameters ('false', 'true', ....)

Comment: as i see your code now, its bit change, i don't know about wordpress but according to this query, Let is explain you